# Find the total size of all files in a directory modified after some time

Tags: bash, unix

I am aware that `find <dirname> -mtime +<time>` allows you to find all of the files modified within a timeframe. Is there a way that I can find the sum of the sizes of the files outputted by this command?

Comment: _Is there a way that I can find the sum of the sizes of the files outputted by this command?_ Most likely, yes. Which part specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

```sh
find ./ -mtime +50 -execdir du -bc {} + | tail -1
```

`find -execdir` will execute the command with each file from the directory as argument.

`du -bc` will check the size of all files passed as argument and print the total size in bytes at the end.

`tail -1` will print the last line with the total amount.

As Oguz Ismail noted, if there are thousands of files and it exceed the number of arguments it can pass as a single call to `du`, it will call du multiple times and only the total from the last call will be seen.

Alternatively then:

```sh
{
  find ./ -mtime +50 -execdir du -b {} + | cut -f1 | tr '\n' '+'
  echo '0'
} | bc
```

Let `du` print the size of each file.

`cut -f1`, capture the size column.

`tr '\n' '+'` replace newline by the `+` sign.

`echo '0'` add an ultimate 0 and newline to the long additions chain to have it not end with the + sign.

`| bc` pipe the long addition to the `bc` calculator.

or more simply:

```sh
{ find . -mtime +50 -printf '%s+'; echo 0; } | bc
```

Or using shell arithmetic:

```sh
total_size=$(($(find . -mtime +50 -printf '%s+')0))
echo $total_size
```

Comment: @oguzismail added alternate total computation that will work with much more files.

Answer (score 2):

In bytes:

```
find . -mtime +1 -printf '%s\n' | awk '{amount+=$NF}END{print amount}'
```

Comment: ^ Also confused about %f but otherwise this is just what I needed, thanks!

Comment: `{ find . -mtime +50 -printf '%s+'; echo 0; } | bc -l` or: `echo $(($(find . -mtime +50 -printf '%s+')0))`